# Best way to provide embedding script?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am providing embeddable content which I distribute with a script tag. When a user includes the script tag in their page's HTML it injects the relevant content into the DOM at the point of execution. They may include several of these embed scripts in the same page.

The embed script has a number of dependencies (jQuery, Google jsapi, Google Fusion tables). I want to be able to load these if they haven't already been loaded by a previous instance of the embed script or by the person who wrote the rest of the page.

The main interesting bits:

1. My embed script may exist several times in a person's page.
2. I have external dependencies.
3. I want to be able to bind to events (`google.maps.event.addDomListener`) with my scripts so I need to wait until those scripts have loaded.
4. I want to avoid messing around with the embedder's page.

Is there a common pattern to achieve this?

Comment: your script embeds the external dependencies by injecting `<script>` tags pointing at those external things. This gets very ugly... I've had to debug ad server code that embeds multiple scripts through a daisy chain 8+ levels deep.

Comment: Yep. Me too. Hence turning to StackOverflow for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm using the Google JS Loader and the dependencies are compatible with it, I'm making use of this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function things_loaded() {
    if(window.THING_MAPS) {
        for (var mapI = 0; mapI < window.THING_MAPS.length; mapI++) {
            window.THING_MAPS[mapI]();
        }
        window.THING_MAPS = [];
    }
}

if (!window.THING_MAPS_LOADED) {
    google.load("jquery", "1.7.0");
    google.load("maps", "3", {other_params:'sensor=false', callback: things_loaded});
    window.THING_MAPS_LOADED = true;
}

</script>
```